# Getting ERROR "[internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10-alpine" when trying to docker-compose up --build

Tags: python, docker, api, docker-compose

Im trying to build my services however when i use docker-compose up --build i recieve the following:

### ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10-alpine                                                    0.9s
=> [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                  0.0s

> [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10-alpine:

---

failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest sha256:075028375723487287022732372384723874283782348237837: not found

This issue is appearing after i've updated my mac to Ventura 13.0.1, from what i gathered it appears to be the os thats causing this issue. I have 2 services(database and api) the db can spin up but my api returns the issue above.

Ive tried:

```
docker-compose up --build     
docker pull docker.io/library/python:3.10-alpine
docker ps -a
```

making sure the docker deamon was running
clearing my images

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  my_db:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    container_name: my_db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
      POSTGRES_DB: "${DB_NAME}"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5432:${DB_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    deploy:
      mode: global
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 128M
    pid: isolated
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    cap_drop:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_ADMIN
    networks:
      - db

  my_api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      posts_db:
        condition: service_healthy
    container_name: my_api
    platform: linux/amd64/v8
    environment:
      CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT: local_docker

      DB_HOST: "${DB_HOST}"
      DB_PORT: "${DB_PORT}"
      DB_NAME: "${DB_NAME}"
      DB_USERNAME: "${DB_USERNAME}"
      DB_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    deploy:
      mode: global
      endpoint_mode: vip
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 128M
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - /app/database
      - ./:/app
    networks:
      - api
      - db


networks:
  api:
  db:
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer i was searching for "--platform =linux/amd64" to my Dockerfile as follows

```
From --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.10-alpine
```

This issue was encountered after i updated my macos to Ventura 13.0.1